# unable to access the DATA CONTRACT properties on client side ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

i'm working on WCF service in which I have a class named as `EmployeeDC`. [DC means DATA Contract Class] and in the interface of that service I have a method named as **callBusinessLayer** and the signature of this method is an **object**. but the problem is While consuming this WCF service on client side I'm unable to access the properties of the class.

I have googled but didn't find any appropriate example in which an object is passing while consuming the service on client side. Please have a look on code snippets and guide me if I'm wrong. Your help will be appreciate.

Thanks

**Code Snippet**

**Service Interface**

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ITestServ
{

    [OperationContract]
    void callBusinessLayer(EmployeeDC empDCObj);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here

}
```

**DataContract Class:**

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeeDC
{
    [DataMember]
    public string userID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string companyID { get; set; }
}
```

P.S : this is not the inner class. I'm using the DAL approach.

**CLIENT SIDE: where Consuming WCF Service**

```
  private void process() 
    {
        ServiceReference.EmployeeDC objDC = new ServiceReference.EmployeeDC();
        objDC. // here im unable to get the DATAMembers

        //Service Call
        ServiceReference.TestServClient tsc = new ServiceReference.TestServClient();
        var testResponse = tsc.callBusinessLayer(**object required**);

        Debug.Print(""+signInEmail);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try updating your service after all the changes?

Comment: @HappyLee thanks for your response, but sorry I didn't get you what actually you are talking about?

Comment: Is the service reference pointing to the updated version of the WCF service?

Comment: yes obviously, I have publish every-time on IIS  when I made some change. @HappyLee

Comment: Take a look at this link - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/215375/WCF-datacontract-problem-unable-to-see-all-datacon